# RUBY + SMASHING jobs won't start

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

The script must receive data via API from the server.

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'net/ldap'


Seh = Rufus::Scheduler.new
Seh.interval('5m') do |job|

$all_pst = RestClient.get 'https://eu.api.knowbe4.com/v1/phishing/security_tests', headers
```

But on startup it throws an error.

```
{ 621740 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
   621740 job:
   621740 Rufus::Scheduler::IntervalJob "5m" {}
   621740 ["/home/user/smashing_proj/jobs/redteamphish.rb", 24]
   621740 error:
   621740 621740
   621740 Net::HTTPServerException
   621740 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:124:in `error!'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:133:in `value'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1009:in `connect'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:970:in `do_start'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:959:in `start'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:727:in `transmit'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:163:in `execute'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:63:in `execute'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient.rb:66:in `get'
   621740 /home/user/smashing_proj/jobs/redteamphish.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:233:in `block in do_call'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:130:in `around_trigger'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:232:in `do_call'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:280:in `trigger_now'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:331:in `block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:317:in `loop'
   621740 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs_core.rb:317:in `block in start_work_thread'
   621740tz:
   621740 ENV['TZ']:
   621740 Time.now: 2023-03-27 07:37:30 +0600
   621740 local_tzone: #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Almaty>
   621740 et-orbi:
   621740 (etz:nil,tnz:"+06",tziv:"2.0.4",tzidv:nil,rv:"3.0.0",rp:"x86_64-linux",win:false,rorv:nil,astz :nil,eov:"1.2.7",eotnz:#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Almaty>,eotnfz:"+0600",eotlzn:"Asia/Almaty",eotnfZ:"+06",debian:" Asia/Almaty",centos:nil,osx:"Asia/Almaty")
   621740 scheduler:
   621740 object_id: 52660
   621740 opts:
   621740 {}
   621740 frequency: 0.3
   621740 scheduler_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x0000556a3daf91f8>
   621740 trigger_lock: #<Rufus::Scheduler::NullLock:0x0000556a3daf91d0>
   621740 uptime: 225891.14396429062 (2d14h44m51.143991947s)
   621740 down?: false
   621740 frequency: 0.3
   621740 discard_past: true
   621740 started_at: #<EtOrbi::EoTime:0x0000556a3daf9158 @seconds=1679655159.6004803, @zone=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Almaty>, @time=nil>
   621740 paused_at: nil
   621740 threads: 2
   621740 thread: #<Thread:0x0000556a3daf90b8 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.8.1/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:630 sleep>
   621740 thread_key: rufus_scheduler_52660
   621740 work_threads: 1
   621740 active: 1
   621740 vacant: 0
   621740 max_work_threads: 28
   621740 mutexes: {}
   621740 jobs: 1
   621740 at_jobs: 0
   621740 in_jobs: 0
   621740 every_jobs: 0
   621740 interval_jobs: 1
   621740 cron_jobs: 0
   621740 running_jobs: 1
   621740 work_queue:
   621740 size: 0
   621740 num_waiting: 0
   621740 join_queue:
   621740 size: 0
   621740 num_waiting: 0
} 621740 .
```

Please advise me which way to go to correct the error.

PS… 3 weeks ago everything worked fine.

Thank you in advance!

Tried thinking initially that the problem is in the date on the server, corrected the date. Registered full access from the machine to the Internet on a proxy server.

Comment: 407 is an authentication issue with a proxy. It's unlikely a timezone issue. Is there a proxy you need to authenticate with first?

Comment: Switched the server with direct access to the Internet. Earned. Thanks for the direction!!!